# Export Eclipse EMF's @generated not in file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf

in my eclipse emf project I have several `@generated NOT` tags.
I think this gets very confusing when I have a lot of changes.

Is there a way to put the changes into a separate file / folder ?!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, that is not possible. EMF generates its code in a way that it pretends that all files are in their correct place.

In general, I don't recommend to change the EMF generated code unless there really is no other way, as it is cumbersome to manage. However, if you replace the generated EFactory instance, it should be possible to replace most (if not all) objects with their descendants, that could be put into another source folder/package.

As a sidenote, maybe using the more or less undeveloped (AFAIK) [Eclipse Mint](http://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF8QFjAA&url=http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mint&ei=jBnWT7zdB6704QS2pvDQAw&usg=AFQjCNFqOajYVwl10vTHpvH86VEAMnnS9w&sig2=J5O5EoGxEqyMi4znwnVyRQ) would help, as it has an extension that colors the Package Explorer based on the generated code (not the best solution, but it is one that helps).

Comment: isn't it possible to make changes using JET templates ?!

Comment: In theory, it is possible to change templates. However, as EClasses refer to each other (at least in normal cases), you have to replace the entire EClass reference method used in the templates to replace all occurences of the specific modified types. If I were you, I would either modify the generated factory to instantiate different EClass descendants, or abandon this separation because of the cost.